# QTableView sorting signal?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtableview, qabstractitemmodel

I use `QTableView` + `QStandardItemModel` to show some data (data stored in some other data structure), and this table view is **sortable**.

Since it is sortable, when sorting this model, I also need to sort the order of stored data. I try to implement a slot for the sorting signal, but I don't know what signal is emitted when clicking the header to start the sorting action.

I tried the clicked signal, but it's only emitted for data row, not for the headerData.
what should I do if I want to do something else while sorting the `QtableView` + `QStandardItemModel` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Header of the View can be obtained by

`QHeaderView * QTableView::horizontalHeader () const`

Now with the obtained `QHeaderView`, you can connect a slot to the signal,

```
void QHeaderView::sectionClicked ( int logicalIndex )   [signal].
```

From the Qt 4.5 documentation, **This signal is emitted when a section is clicked. The section's logical index is specified by logicalIndex.Note that the sectionPressed signal will also be emitted.**

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

The Header view mentioned above has signal `sortIndicatorChanged(int, Qt::SortOrder)` so it might be smarter to use it

Also, you might want to have a look into `QSortFilterProxyModel` 
more details here http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#details

Comment: sortIndicatorChanged is fired before sorting. sectionClicked not.