# Qt Qtableview not getting signal for header item clicking

Tags: qtableview

I am using `Qtableview` with `QsqlTableModel` for populating a table data. I want to sort the column based on user selection on column header.

I tried the way mentioned in [QTableView sorting signal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081340/qtableview-sorting-signal) for getting the signal (get the horizontal header from `QtableView` and connect signal `sectionclicked(int logical index)`. But the same signal is not getting emitted when i click on column header.

Please find the code where connection is done:

**Member variable:**

```
QHeaderView *m_horiz_header;
```

**.cpp file**

```
m_sqltablemodel->setTable(tabel_name);
m_sqltablemodel->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
m_sqltablemodel->select();

m_horiz_header= m_table_view->horizontalHeader();
connect(m_horiz_header, SIGNAL(sectionClicked ( int logicalIndex ) ),
    this, SLOT(on_sectionClicked ( int logicalIndex ) ));
```

**Slot function for sorting:**

```
void class::on_sectionClicked ( int logicalIndex ) 
{
    m_horiz_header->setSortIndicator(logicalIndex, Qt::AscendingOrder);
    m_table_view->sortByColumn(logicalIndex);
}
```

This function is not getting called, when column header is clicked.

Can you please help me how to do this, where I went wrong?

Comment: Related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24714130/qt-5-3-qtreeview-clickable-header-data

Answer (score 8):

I got the reason why the signal connection failed.

argument name should not be mentioned on connect.

```
connect(m_horiz_header, SIGNAL(sectionClicked(int)), this, SLOT(on_sectionClicked(int)));
```

by modifiying the above code like this, it worked.