# Qt 5.3 QTreeView clickable header data

Tags: c++, qt

How can i do clickable columns in QTreeView? And how i can handle column clicked event?

That is my code:

```
QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel(ui->treeView);
ui->treeView->setModel(model);
model->setColumnCount(2);
model->setRowCount(5);

model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, new QStandardItem("Title"));
model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, new QStandardItem("Year"));

model->setItem(0, 0, new QStandardItem("Black Bullet"));
model->setItem(0, 1, new QStandardItem("2014"));
```

Comment: You need to work with `QHeaderView` throught `QTreeView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define an instance of `QHeaderView`, and set its clickable property to true. Then you can connect the clicks to your slot. In PySide/PyQt:

```
horizontalHeaders = self.view.header() #QHeaderView instance
horizontalHeaders.setClickable(True)
horizontalHeaders.sectionClicked.connect(self.headerClicked)
```

It will automatically send the section (column index) clicked to headerClicked(self, section).